# Mount usb drive as regular user in debian/sid

Tags: debian, polkit

I'm using debian sid, and since one of the upgrades I cannot normally mount usb drive (sdcard).

In dolphin it results in message saying "Not authorized to perform operation"
[image: dolpihin-in-error]

So after some reading it seems that in background it is doing

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdj1
```

This one ends with "==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount ===" and it asks for root password.

After some reading I found out that this could be policy-kit
So I added
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/emil-can-mount-usb.pkla

```
[mounting without password]
Identity=unix-user:emil
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

After adding this nothing has changed. Dolphin cannot mount, CLI asks for a password.
So I tried debuggin it by stopping polkit service and started it manually

```
/usr/libexec/polkitd > /tmp/polkitd.log 2>&1
```

Then in logs I can see the following

```
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.602: system-bus-name::1.37 is inquiring whether system-bus-name::1.1748 is authorized for org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.603:  user of caller is unix-user:root
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.603:  user of subject is unix-user:emil
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.603: checking whether system-bus-name::1.1748 is authorized for org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.603:   0x7f97ac00c4a0
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.604: Checking whether session 1 is active.
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.604: Session 1 has UID 1000.
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.604: UID 1000 has state online.
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.604:  subject is in session 1 (local=1 active=0)
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.604:  challenge (implicit_authorization = auth_admin)
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.604:  
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.609: Added authentication agent for unix-process:31011:409192549 at name :1.1748 [udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdj1], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale pl_PL.UTF-8
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.611: system-bus-name::1.37 is inquiring whether system-bus-name::1.1748 is authorized for org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.611:  user of caller is unix-user:root
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.612:  user of subject is unix-user:emil
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.612: checking whether system-bus-name::1.1748 is authorized for org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.613:   0x7f97ac00a530
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.613: Checking whether session 1 is active.
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.613: Session 1 has UID 1000.
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.613: UID 1000 has state online.
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.613:  subject is in session 1 (local=1 active=0)
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.614:  challenge (implicit_authorization = auth_admin)
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.614:  
** (polkitd:27925): DEBUG: 17:39:58.614:  using authentication agent for challenge
(polkitd:27925): GLib-DEBUG: 17:39:58.614: setenv()/putenv() are not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
(polkitd:27925): GLib-DEBUG: 17:39:58.614: setenv()/putenv() are not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
```

1000 is UID of mine user "emil", but what does it mean
"system-bus-name::1.37 is inquiring whether system-bus-name::1.1748 is authorized for org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount" Why it is not checking bu user, but by process-id

**In summary my question is: How can I fix this (no password asked, and file-managers just opens this).**